# What makes OpenPGP keyrings trustworthy?

Tags: linux, security, pgp, digital-signature, openpgp

I've started reading the Linux From Scratch book and in the first few chapters, you are required to download the sources of all software packages you will need during the installation.
The book provides md5sums to "verify" that the downloads worked, but from a security perspective this is obviously not sufficient.

Since a big part of installing LFS is learning how things work, I've decided that I wanted to verify the signatures for my source tarballs (or at least a few of them).
So I headed over to the GNU FTP server (`https://ftp.gnu.org/`), and they require you to download their keyring from `ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg` which contains public keys of many developers for verifying the tarball signatures.

My question now is, what makes this keyring trustworthy? As far as I can see (and I assume I'm overlooking something), there is still a single point of failure, namely the GNU FTP server. If an attacker were to take control of that server, he could just include his own public key in the keyring and then begin to sign his own malicious tarballs, right?

Is the keyring itself signed with another public key belonging to the GNU project or is there some other layer of security I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, keys are validated in OpenPGP through the web of trust. This is a network consisting of different keys and certifications issued in-between them. By following such paths (called trust paths), you can extend the set of keys you trust.

You always need some sort of trust anchor: you need to be sure about some key(s), which you already validated. Often, this is done on conferences which host key signing parties. You could also trust some servers (for example, based on transport encryption), but this is exactly what you try *not* to do.

Apart from explicit trust, there's also the concept of "TOFU": *trust on first use*. An attacker will hardly be able to provide manipulated software packages over different distribution channels and a long time. Try to find sources of the key you're already using (for example, in a Linux distribution you fetched years ago or on old computer magazine DVDs). Are there copies hosted in some kind of software repositories not under direct control of the original project? Is archive.org listing the OpenPGP key since years? Ask friends whether they have traces of the keys. Most Linux distributions ship a whole set of keys used for signing software.

This is nothing easy to do, and it involves quite some work, but if you properly want to validate a signature, there is no other way.